# Expression meaning - Trying to dig out from minus a million points

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this expression mean?

"Trying to dig out from minus a million points"

As far as I understand, "to dig out" means to find, to unearth.

A point means, e.g., a credit card point.  There is also an expression "(someone) has a point", meaning that what they have said is important and should be considered.

But what is "minus a million points" in this context, I don't understand.

Comment: What is the context? Where did you encounter it? You can find various potentially relevant slang/informal meanings for "[dig out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dig_out)", but I can only guess about the points, which might be literal spikes, some kind of numerical penalty, or some kind of [imaginary scoring system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_points).

Comment: I think the question is valid as it is a good example of not using an idiom in full.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom, fully loaded, in English is:
**to dig oneself out of a hole.**

That said, *many people play around with idioms*. This is merely a case of that.

Trying to dig oneself out of a hole created by having "minus a million points". [whatever that last thing might mean[

- Trying to dig oneself out of a mountain of debt

*Credit cards do not have points per se. Points as a positive things*. People have credit ratings based on the payment habits. That is, do they make payments on time or not? When they do not their rating goes down.

**These are called credit cards scores:**

What is considered a good credit score?
Credit score ranges and what they mean will vary based on the scoring model used to calculate them, but they are generally similar to the following:

300-579: Poor
580-669: Fair
670-739: Good
740-799: Very good
800-850: Excellent

[Hyperfax credit card rating outfit](https://www.equifax.com/personal/education/credit/score/what-is-a-credit-score/#:%7E:text=300%2D579%3A%20Poor,740%2D799%3A%20Very%20good)

**The higher the score, the better.**

So, "minus a million points" does not make sense for a credit card score.
It must be some other thing like a game where you can lose points for something.